# js unexpected result from array.push(item)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I try (or better I usualy use) the js array for collecting different items (eg.: numbers or objects). Pretty easy, or? How it can happen that I can get the result with right number of items but every stored item is the same as the last one?

```
 array.push(item0)
 array.push(item1)
 array.push(item2)
 ...
 array.push(itemX)
```

will result in

```
array[itemX, itemX, itemX, ..., itemX]
```

**Does anyone ever experienced this?**
I experience this in a specific development context (Angular 8.2) while I try to store the output (everytime the output is emitted) from one component to the service's array, but I guess it should be anything behind and my tired mind cannot figure it out :(

The angular service is

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  data: any[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  addItem(item: any): void {
    this.data.push(item);
  }

  downloadData(): void {
    console.log('data', this.data);
  }

}
```

and in component I use it

```
<app-other-component
 (done)="collectData($event)"
></app-other-component>
```

```
import {DataService} from '../data-service.service';

export class MainCopmponent {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService){}

  collectData(data: any): void {
    this.dataService.addItem(data);
  }  

}
```

OtherComponent looks like this

```
interface Data {
 item1: number,
 item2: number,
 item3: string
}

export class OtherComponent {

 @Output() done: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

 private data: Data = {
  item1: null,
  item2: null,
  item3: undefined
 }

 collectData(data: any): void {
  this.data.item1 = data.item1;
  this.data.item2 = data.item2;
  this.data.item3 = data.item3;

  this.emitData();
 }

 private emitData(): void {
  this.done.emit(this.data);
 }



}
```

Comment: Can you please add the surrounding code?

Comment: The code you've shown isn't enough for anyone to debug this issue. Sometimes a messed up if statement can do this for instance `if(item0 = itemX)` rather than `if(item0 == itemX)` but that is a stab in the dark

Comment: 1. Don't put that in a comment, it's hard to read, edit your post instead. And 2. the missing part is how `addItem` is called, where probably the problem lies (it's inside a `for` loop, isn't it?).

Comment: the function collectData is called every time the 'done' event inside the 'other-component' is emitted. While I log the emitting event, all the data are fresh and unique..., while I call dataService.downloadData(), the result is as I described..., all the items are as same as the last one...

Comment: The problem should not be inside the service component, however I tried to collect 'other-component' result within the main-component too, whith the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks as if the object was being reused (so, by modifying `itemX`, you're modifying the object `item1`, `item2` etc. are referring to). The root of the problem is most likely inside `app-other-component` and should be fixed there. You can, however, fix it for example in `DataService`. This should work:

```
addItem(item: any): void {
// this is one generic way of cloning an object; the gist: don't push `item`, push its copy
    this.data.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item))); 
}
```

Comment: This figured out my problem! Thank You. But I still cannot understand how this can happen... I will explain more `app-other-component` in my original question.

Comment: It's the "by reference vs by value" problem. The simplest example: `const foo = { name: foo }; const bar = foo; bar.name = "bar"; console.log(foo.name); // logs "bar"`.